# Couldn't Marvel use any of the Avengers characters?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers

So, it's been pointed out, with the use of Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch in the "Ultron" movie, that the reason this was allowed is because they were both part of the Avengers team at some point, and Marvel has the rights to use any member of the team(paraphrasing my understanding of it). Also, it's been said that another studio owns the rights to the Hulk movies, but again, he's an Avenger, and thus able to be in those movies, but we won't get a Marvel Hulk movie. That being said, could Marvel simply use Spider-Man, Wolverine, and others in the Avengers movies?

Comment: **<comments removed>** Take the discussion to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in [this article](http://screenrant.com/joss-whedon-avengers-2-quicksilver-scarlet-witch-x-men/) and [this article](http://www.hitfix.com/motion-captured/why-are-fox-and-marvel-having-a-showdown-over-x-men-and-the-avengers-2), sort of, but not quite.

Since they *are* crossover members, they could technically use characters that go by that name, but "with certain restrictions".

Consider Scarlet Witch and Quicksilver, who were originally introduced in the comics as Mutants, back in [X-Men issue #4](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/12488/uncanny_x-men_1963_4). They have specific backgrounds (e.g. they are the children of Magneto) and sources of their powers (born with them).

In the Fox-Movie universe, Quicksilver is a mutant, born with his powers, and there's even a quick nod in *Days of Future Past* to his possible parentage.

In the MCU, their parents are dead, and their father is presumably not Magneto, and their powers were given to them via experimentation. In fact, Scarlet Witch's powers aren't even her normal comic powers.

This all falls in line with the rumors that Marvel was allowed to use the characters as long as they made no mention of any "mutants", as all of those rights are held by Fox.

The same would go for any other characters left out of Marvel's ownership rights, unless they came to a specific agreement. Without permission from, or an agreement with Sony (thankfully, they worked one out!), Marvel would have to change Spider-Man dramatically - something they could probably get away with with characters like Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch, as they're lesser known by the average viewer, but not really the case with Spider-Man or Wolverine.

Comment: Yeah, it's those articles that got me wondering if they _could_ do the same with other characters. Not that they should, necessarily. But _could_ they.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks With enough lawyers, anything is possible

Comment: @MyCodeSucks unfortunately, the deals and agreements have been shrouded in secrecy for some reason. a lot of it is just informed speculation and info from "a guy in the know"

Comment: @JasonBaker: LOL, fair enough.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Obviously none of us have seen the contracts, but everything we've read/heard indicates that Quicksilver & Scarlet were given an explicit special exemption inthe Fox deal, right from the start, probably *because* they were also Avengers.

Comment: And because they are largely considered to be members of the classic Avengers team, whereas Spider-Man and Wolverine are not.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: But that's why I ask. Cause so was Wolverine.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks right, but I'd bet my life savings that Fox was never going to agree to a deal where they got the X-Men, but *didn't* get exclusive rights to Wolverine.

Comment: Wolverine is a fairly recent Avengers recruit. Scarlet Witch & Quicksilver were some of the original recruits.

Comment: ... and we should probably move this to chat if you have any further questions :)

Comment: @MyCodeSucks we have a comic movie/show chat room [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19346/agents-of-nothing), or you're welcome to create a separate one if you prefer.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks it may also have to do with how the character is perceived by the public. Although comic readers know that Wolverine and Beast are both Avengers, to most people they're associated with the X-Men. The twins, however, are more commonly associated with The Avengers.